# Install gitlab runner on a server but as multiple different user

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to have gitlab runner installed on a server, but run as different user, so that when user1 commit a code, gitlab runner will run as user1; when user2 commit a code, gitlab runner will run as user2?

I ask this because we are not allowed to create one user specifically for gitlab-runner. As our deployment script requires sudo command, and each of our account on the server have a password that expires every 24 hours, and to retrieve password we need to go through 2FA. So the account access on server is a nightmare.

Currently with the above restriction, only one developer can deploy the code since gitlab runner on the server can only run as him.

If gitlab runner can run as the user that commit the code, then it will be possible for multiple user to push code and deploy.

Anyone has a good solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Why you not use runner with docker containers? Inside containers you didn't have problem with user and you didn't need to have multiple runners running